# Navigate to another page after login

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to navigate to new page after login. When i click on login i get error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'menu/dashboard'.

my app.routing is:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'auth',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then( m => m.AuthPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'menu',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/menu/menu.module').then( m => m.MenuPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then( m => m.DashboardPageModule)
  }
```

auth.routing looks something like this:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
```

menu.routing looks something like this:

```
{
    path: 'menu',
    component: MenuPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardPageModule)
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/menu/dashboard'
  }
```

and my function on login.component is:

```
fnLogin() {
    this.router.navigate(['/menu']);
  }
```

can someone please tell why i'm not able to navigate to dashboard page?

Comment: replace path: 'menu' with path: ' ' in menu.routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write ::

`this.router.navigate(['menu/menu']);`

or, I would suggest to change

`path:'menu'` to `path:''` in menu routing module

If changed, you can just write

`this.router.navigate(['menu']);` which you already wrote and it will work.

Comment: Hi Akhil, thankyou for reply. Sorry it's not working.

Comment: If you want to navigate to dashboard, then you'll need to write menu/menu/dashboard

Comment: If that's not the case, then please explain what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Also, you wrote redirectTo as menu/ dashboard... But actually we need write name of the path in redirectTo but not any route